# WCF service. How can I return custom error/info page

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service. How I can remove default WCF info/error pages. And return own custom page or JSON result?

For example WCF default info page

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use  Application_EndRequest event of iis.

```
   protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // you could decide whether to redirect according to the path and status code
       string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode == 400)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/ErrorPage.aspx");
        }

    }
```

Please don't forget to ensure wcf runs in compatibility mode.

```
 <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"></serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

And above your service

```
 [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class CalculatorService : ICalculatorService
```

Or the Application_EndRequest event won't fire.